# How to check your version of Windows Universal C runtime programatically with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that is scanning remote PC's for specific file versions for Visual Studio C++ and Windows Universal C Runtime.  I have the VSC++ check completed via this command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.PCName -ScriptBlock {((Get-Item 
$env:windir\system32\msvcp140.dll).VersionInfo).ProductVersion}
```

The issue is I'm not sure which file to check to when it comes to the Windows Universal C Runtime.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about Ucrtbase.dll?

Comment: Thanks!  I will give that a try.